# jQuery smooth scroll on same page & different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

I'm creating a one-page website and I've found a small script for smooth scrolling and it works perfectly. But, if you leave the homepage and go to a single post or eventpage, the navigation doesn't work anymore because the anchor isn't on the existing page.

And another issue, when scrolling manually, it would be awesome if the active link could change class like it does when you click it.

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#primary-menu li a").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $('#primary-menu li').removeClass('current_page_item ');
    $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
    $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 68 } , 1000);

} ); } );
```